# ServiceStack 4.0 with Microsoft Application Insights Telemetry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack, azure-application-insights

Working on MS project default Web Application Template and planning to use Application Insights to monitor WEB API. Is there any efficient way to configure Insights on root level like it's done for example in standard Web Application projects with controllers and views (adding a script in layout page)?

Service stack has no views or controllers in project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of [ServiceStack Project Templates](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5bd40817-0986-444d-a77d-482e43a48da7) are configured to use Application Insights, so the easiest approach is to create an Empty ASP.NET Web Application that's pre-configured with App Insights and [Install ServiceStack from NuGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Create-your-first-webservice) on the empty ASP.NET project.